# 500 Internal Server Error while connecting worklight using WL.Client.connect in Worklight 8

Tags: android, angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I'm new to worklight and migrating worklight 6.2 to 8. I'm trying to connecting worklight using following code,

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('mfpready', function() {

     WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
     WL.Client.connect({ onSuccess: onConnectSuccess, onFailure: onConnectFailure });

        angular.bootstrap(document, [ 'App' ]);
        WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
        .then(
            function () {
                console.log("*** Obtained token successfully.");
            },
            function () {
                console.log("*** Failed obtaining token.");
            }
        );
     }, false);
    document.addEventListener('mfpjsloaded', function() {

    WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
    WL.Client.connect({ onSuccess: onConnectSuccess, onFailure: onConnectFailure });

        angular.bootstrap(document, [ 'App' ]);
        WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
        .then(
            function () {
                console.log("*** Obtained token successfully.");
            },
            function () {
                console.log("*** Failed obtaining token.");
            }
        );

    }, false);
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent('mfpready',  function() {
    WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); });
}


function onConnectSuccess(result){
        console.log("Success to connect worklight :"+JSON.stringify(result));
    }

    function onConnectFailure(result){
        console.log("Fail to connect worklight :"+JSON.stringify(result));
    }
```

But I got following error,

```
{"status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error","responseText":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>\n<p>The server encountered an internal error or\nmisconfiguration and was unable to complete\nyour request.</p>\n<p>Please contact the server administrator,\n you@your.address and inform them of the time the error occurred,\nand anything you might have done that may have\ncaused the error.
```

and facing one more error,

```
static_app_props.js:3 Running static_app_props.js...
angular.js:107 ReferenceError: WLResourceRequest is not defined
```

Please guild me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error message is custom. It is not coming from MFP. Do you have a webserver or proxy fronting MFP ? If so, you should check if it is getting the request and sending this response back. Verify how far the request flows.

Comment: Even while register app using mfpdev app register my-server-profile we are facing this issue Reason: Failed to set runtime details.: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0: HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: Is there a "<" somewhere in the information you provided? Check this line "Reason: Failed to set runtime details.: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: we are able to connect worklight server after worklight libs are changed